# Raise more ether in Parity POA chains

Tags: mining, private-blockchain, parity

From the [wiki](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Private-chains) of private chains in parity

> Parity also includes Proof of Authority Chains which do not require
>   mining.

Is it possible to raise more ether in an existing POA chain?

### Use case

Lets suppose I started a private chain with one account. Now that account used up its ether. Now there is no way to mine ether, since mining POA does not require mining. How do I raise more ether?

Answer (score 0):

As said by @rphmeier on gitter channel:

> currently there isn't support, but we are planning to add a feature
>   where a contract can perform non-canonical state transition by issuing
>   events the contract could be operated by an administrator or require
>   majority signatures from validators as a barrier to issue events a
>   sophisticated contract could have linked credentials for the
>   validators themselves so they don't have to use their own keys, and
>   impose limits on the magnitude of changes that can be made over time